# convert decimal random values to binary for ent testing

Tags: random-number-generator, random

I have ascii random values from /dev/urandom in a file like:
435
678
437
897

They are uniformly distributed and have perfect average. feeding the file to ent test suite yields low entropy value and high mean value (far from 127.5 which is random) as ent is meant to test binary files. I am using linux, how can I convert a file with decimal random values from /dev/random to its original bytes format so that it can show correct ent results.

Comment: In other words, if I have decimal random values and I need to test their entropy, how can I convert them to the original form in binary so I can test them and get the correct result.

Comment: How about https://smallseotools.com/text-to-binary/ ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268952/using-dev-random-dev-urandom-to-generate-random-data